# check using js/java if the browsing happens in the same window same tab

Tags: javascript, java

Is there any way in javascript to check if the browsing is happening on the same page tab in the same window or is it happening in different window? If not in javascript, by communicating with the backend built using java

Comment: What do you mean by browsing? Catching events from other windows / frames, like mouse-over?

Comment: Suppose I navigateTo a page in a firefox window. Then I use the same window instance for further browsing in the same tab. Later I start another firefox browser instance and start navigating to the webpages in it in one tab. Is there a way in js to differentiate whether the events happen on which of the instances

Comment: I don't think you can tell that by JS. Maybe tell us what are you trying to do?

Comment: Im developing an app that records and playsback whatever a user does by giving a starting entry domain name. So if there are many windows when recording I need to know where the event was performed to get the action and details to save it to play it back

Comment: Are you writing a browser extension ? Permissions level are not the same for web and ://chrome scripts. For chrome browser your may want to have a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs You'll probably be able to get what you want from these two APIs.

Comment: its an app, not an extension

Comment: `app` doesn't mean anything for me... At a least, it's a special directory type on osX system. Can you clarify ?

Comment: if JS is not gonna help as its tied to a specific window, can I do it in the backend using java, do I need to check for processes and what all are running and check if anything new is added or existing is used?

Comment: I think your question is about how to design your client server system, not about JavaScript.

Comment: I initially thought if its possible in js to do in js as its little easier

Comment: Well extensions are written in js. All you need is to get enough permissions to run the APIs I linked you to. But since you don't tell us the details, we can't help. I'll try to be less dumb and guess it's a standalone java application, run on client's machine. Then since I don't know nothing about java, as a lot of people lurking at the [tag:javascript] tag, I would advice you to edit your question or even write a new one, specifically with the [tag:java] tag and **more background info**.

Comment: ya sure, my bad..

Comment: Please also edit the content, this won't mean anything for a [java] person... You are asking *"Can I do X with javascript"*. Explain to us wher you are coming from. Why you need this. What you have tried. In the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

This might answer you partially.

You can listen for `visibilitychange` event of `document`. This event would be fired when you switch browser tabs or windows.

Nice exmaple from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web application in different windows (be it in one browser or in another browser) then those client applications interact with the server by sending http requests.

Your server can look at those requests and per se will only see the IP address, which is not enough information to differentiate different browser windows on that machine.

So you have to add that information.

E.g. you could send a bit of information (a token), e.g. a unique number to the client in one of the early http exchanges and insist that the client application puts its token into every of its requests. This establishes a primitive session, meaning you can group (and identify!) various http requests together.

Comment: ya, but this involves to much overhead, is there a way to use the list of processes running in the OS to find the initiation is on which pid?

Comment: Let us assume you are able to find out the id of the browser process. How will that help you identify different windows in that browser? And what then, how did you plan to access that data from your OS level application?